# Muting audio when video is not being played in complex filtergraph

Tags: ffmpeg

My goal is to silence audio till when the appropriate video is playing.

This is what I tried

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:4.061 -i b.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:8.016 -i c.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:12.016 -i d.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=3,volume=0[a0];[1:a]adelay=4061[a1];[a0][a1]amerge=inputs=2[audio]..." -map "[audio]" ... -r 60 -vcodec h264 zusammen.mp4
```

It starts playing together at the start to be overlayed at 4061. How do I hear the audio in sync with video while what is not being played is muted?

Comment: Show the missing part of your command that is hidden with `...`.

Comment: @llogan See https://superuser.com/questions/1526432/mute-audio-streams-selectively

Comment: It is discouraged to ask the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites. I would have eventually seen your duplicate question at SU.

Comment: @llogan It is encouraged to ask the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Read the docs. It does not conflict with the link you mentioned. Regardless, crossposting is helping everyone.

Comment: Cross-posting is generally _not_ allowed. Read the answers on the linked meta post and the related posts on the same site. It wastes time of volunteers and spreads information over several sites.

Comment: @VitalisHommel Where in the docs does it indicate that crossposting is encouraged? Please provide a link. Even the creator of Stack Exchange says ["do not cross-post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073/). The problem with crossposting in ffmpeg in particular is that there are way more users asking ffmpeg Qs than answering. Answering can take significant time, and I can't do this all day, so there is limited time to answer. It is inefficient to answer a question and then see the crosspost already with the same solution. Other Qs then suffer.

Comment: @ModusTollens Cross-posting generally is allowed. Read the answers on the linked meta post and the related posts on the same site. It saves time of volunteers and generates exposure.

Comment: @llogan You created great replies in other threads to ffmpeg. Why don't you reply to this one or ask targeted questions regarding the issue?

Comment: @VitalisHommel You can bring that up on meta if you care about it. I'll stop discussing here because it is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @ModusTollens You shouldn't even have joined in the first place if that was your sole goal. We are here to discuss ffmpeg issues and that is all that matters.

Comment: @VitalisHommel I ran out of time explaining why crossposting is a time suck. Maybe tomorrow.